# Installation of npm lite-server gives an error

Tags: npm, npm-install, ethereum, solidity, lite-server

While following the [Petshop tutorial](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop), the final step requires the installation of **lite-server** from npm for the project to run on my browser (Firefox).

I tried the following command for installation, with PowerShell in administrator mode:

> **npm i lite-server -g**

This gave me the following error message:

> **npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...61d4d38b3260af8ae4e7"'**
>
> **npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!**
>   **C:\Users\Ubaba\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-09T10_10_51_353Z-debug.log**

I tried all the solutions mentioned on [this page](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/9), but none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an issue with the NPM mirror

Try this : `npm cache clean --force`
and after retry install Lite-server.

regards